# Access the config file deployed with war file inside Intellij Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, deployment

I used to deploy my war file by placing it inside the /Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat8.5/webapps folder.  For simplicity, I have a config file also inside the same folder that the war file reference to.

However, working now with Tomcat directly in Intellij, which deploys my war file directly to Tomcat within Intellij, what is the new directory to place my config file in?

I think before I found a way to override the default Intellij Tomcat deployment directory to my /Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat8.5/webapps folder.  This way I didn't have to place my config in a location.  Is there a tutorial on this?

Thanks.

Comment: please add the position of your config file to your question. Is it located in `webapps/<yourWebApp>/WEB-INF/classes` ? Or is it in `webapps/<yourWebApp>/` ? If the latter, you shouldn't do that, because it is exposed to the users

Comment: @JimHawkins Thanks for the suggestion.  I am simply putting it inside /webapps which like you said is exposed to the users, but this is only for my own testing purpose for now.  Is there a way for Intellij to deploy from this folder?